# Изменение данных в словаре. iOS.Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift

Проблема следующая: В моем приложениии можно войти через разные соц. сети. Если аккаунт в соц. сетях записан на разные емэйлы, то и входной аккаунт будет разным, и соответсвенно токен получаемый с сервера будет разным. Когда я получаю токен, то сохраняю его в юзер дефолтс, чтобы потом при загрузке определенного экрана его использовать. И когда я меняю аккаунты (но не выхожу из приложения), я всегда получаю новый токен (токен, соответствующий данному аккаунту) и в юзер дефолтс все отлично сохраняется и работает. Но когда я пытаюсь загрузить определенный экран, то у меня в словаре всегда хранится старый токен. Словарь я использую, чтобы использовать его в запросе. Но когда я выхожу из приложения и снова захожу, то в словарь у меня записывается верный токен из юзер дефолтс.

Словарь выглядит так:

```
var parameters = ["api_token": "\(token!)"]
```

Пытался и обновить так:

```
parameters.updateValue("\(token!)", forKey: "api_token")
```

Почему так происходит? Никак не хочет меняться.

Вообще странная тема. Почему у меня словарь вообще сохраняется, когда я выхожу из функции?! Хотя это cluss func

Comment: Хотя в другом месте кода, у меня есть точно такой же момент, но вместо токена, там записываются другие данные и они отлично работают. Странная тема....

Comment: Ответ найден! Всем кто принимал участие большое спасибо!)))

Comment: и в чем оказалась проблема?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, там ошибка не словаре было, как оказалось... Я сохранял токен в статическую переменную, чтобы потом ее везде использовать, но она у меня могла обновиться только при новом запуске приложения. Просто сделал так, чтобы она снова обновлялась) Детская ошибка по сути)

Comment: ну публикуйте свой ответ тогда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кому интересно, там ошибка не в словаре было, как оказалось... Я сохранял токен в статическую переменную, чтобы потом ее везде использовать, но она у меня могла обновиться только при новом запуске приложения. Просто сделал так, чтобы она снова обновлялась.